# Optim() Function for multiple variables with different boundary conditions in R

Tags: r, optimization, statistics

Could someone help me with setting up function `optim()' for two variables with different boundary conditions?

```
    x = rnorm(1:100)
    y = rnorm(1:100)*50+2
    #ndays is a vector of two values

    test=function(ndays, x, y){ sum(x*ndays[1] - (x^2)*ndays[2] + y^2) }

    optim(par = c(2,10),test, x=x, y=y, lower=c(1,10),upper=c(20,30), method="L-BFGS-B")
    $par
    [1] 20 30
```

Clearly, this optimisation didn't work as ndays[2] should be 10.

If `optim()` is not a good function to apply here, would you be recommending some other function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optim` minimizes the function `test`, which is decreasing when `ndays[2]` increases.

So getting 30 is correct. Also `ndays[1]` will be equal to 20 if `mean(x) < 0` and equal to 1 if `mean(x) > 0`

Comment: Thanks, You are right, I got it confused when I was trying to make up an example to demonstrate my issue. So let's assume this function is more complicated and simulated values always lie on the boundary, how could I deal with it? Do you have any tips I can borrow?